# eCommerce website design concerns

Tags: website-design, ecommerce

I am designing my own eCommerce website. I have few queries on this:

1. Are the templates always the best option? Are these easy to customize?
2. Are there any FREE WYSIWYG web-page design tools that also automate CSS design?
3. I am going to use PHP and MySQL as back-end. What standards my website must comply so that it renders well on all popular browsers? Is there any good resource?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather large set of questions that really doesn't have an easy set of answers. First off, if you are looking for a WYSIWYG editor for the HTML/CSS I am going to assume it's because you're not comfortable with the two. If this is the case then designing an e-commerce site on your own probably isn't quite in your reach yet (I could be wrong, but this is just my opinion). Second the PHP/MYSQL isn't so much what controls how anything will look on a browser. It is how you display the data returned from these technologies with the HTML/CSS that will control this. You need to know that making a good and secure e-commerce website will require an advanced working knowledge of the two and isn't something that can just be done as a beginner project (I'm not sure what your experience with the two are). And thirdly templates are easy to edit as long as you are comfortable editing CSS/HTML. If you're not comfortable editing those then no, they are not easy to edit :)

Comment: Yep, even for veteran programmers, the best move is usually still to deploy an existing e-commerce platform designed, developed, tested, and maintained by a full-time development team. Unless you have very basic needs or have very specific requirements that can't be met by any existing solutions, there's no need to re-invent the wheel. An e-commerce app that you spend 2 months developing isn't going to be as good as one culminating from the work of several developers over the years. It won't be as mature or robust, and in the end will probably cost you more time & money.

Answer (score 1):

grab the copy of www.magentocommerce.com customize the skin and take a few weeks off